# Robot localization Ignoring IMU

Tags: ros, imu, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I Have tried to followed all the information available in the forum regarding imu and robot localization without luck.
Context:
I am using the [Robot localization package](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) to fuse my IMU with my encoders.
I have tried increasing the robot localization threshold, and set all the parameters, I have checked the /diagnostic topic and it says the package should be running fine, i have enabled debugging to find the errors but i am not being able, i attach the debug information returned, the demo was running with the robot still in place and moving the imu.

here are the logs from robot localization https://justpaste.it/7vwyf

and here my configuration of the robot localization package

```
frequency: 30
two_d_mode: true
publish_tf: false

base_link_frame: base_link
world_frame: map
map_frame: map
odom_frame: odom

imu0: Imu
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
          false,  false,  true,
          false, false, false,
          false,  false,  true,
          true,  false,  false]

imu0_differential: true
odom0: odom_raw
odom0_config: [true, true, false,
           false, false, false,
           true, true, false,
           false, false, true,
           false, false, false]

odom0_differential: true

imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 100
imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 10
imu0_angular_velocity_rejection_threshold: 10
debug: true
debug_out_file: /home/add/Escritorio/Test


process_noise_covariance: [0.05, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                          0.0, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                          0.0, 0.0, 0.06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                          0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                          0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                          0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                          0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                          0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                          0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                          0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                          0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                          0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.02, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                          0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0,
                                          0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0,
                                          0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.015]

initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                  0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                  0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                  0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                  0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-9,  0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-9,  0,    0,    0,
                                                  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-9, 0,    0,
                                                  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-9, 0,
                                                  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-9]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361780/robot-localization-ignoring-imu/) by [nalistic](https://answers.ros.org/users/55256/nalistic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have `imu0_differential: true` which is going to take the derivative of the of the two terms that your IMU is providing you (omega_z and a_x). If you take the derivative of those they are going to become angular acceleration and jerk respectively, both values which the filter does not use. Set `imu0_differential: false` and you should see the correct behavior assuming nothing else is wrong. Please let us know!

**The Real Answer**: The problem was that the tf tree had been configured to have multiple odom frames contrary to best practices established in [REP105](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html). Also the configuration file above had the `world_frame` set to "map", when it needs to be set to "odom" for a robot_localization node producing the `odom->base_link` tf.

---

Originally posted by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) with karma: 977 on 2020-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nalistic](https://answers.ros.org/users/55256/nalistic/) on 2020-09-17**:
Thanks a lot for the response! Ill test tommorrow early in the morning and update the post.

**Comment by [nalistic](https://answers.ros.org/users/55256/nalistic/) on 2020-09-18**:
I have already test it without luck no different appreciated,

here i am sharing what the robot localization debug returns for the imu (while wheels encoders are posting 0) https://justpaste.it/7vwyf

also here is my tf in case it is something wrong wih it

```
transforms.push_back(tf::StampedTransform(
     tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(0, 0, 1, 0), tf::Vector3(0.15, 0.0, 0.15)),
    ros::Time::now(),"base_link", "laser"));
transforms.push_back( tf::StampedTransform(
    tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(0, 0, 1, 0), tf::Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
    ros::Time::now(),"base_link", "imu_link"));
```

the imu messages and the odometry (encoders) look fine, they are in the odom and imu_link frames

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-18**:
Just a tip, do `rosrun tf view_frames` to get a graphical output of the frames. I have found many problems using this tool that I would not have otherwise. I will try to read that debug output when I have a chance today.

**Comment by [nalistic](https://answers.ros.org/users/55256/nalistic/) on 2020-09-21**:
It doesnt let me upload the view_frame to ros anwers, but maybe my issue is with the tf, the odom_raw is an odometry message with child_frame_id "odom_raw" and frame_id "base_link", is that set up correct? since there is no parent_frame_id thats the only solution i managed to make the odom_raw (odometry from encoders) child of the base link

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-21**:
In order to conform with [REP 105](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) and the best practice of the robot_localization package your odom_raw odometry message should have the `frame_id`=odom and `child_frame_id`=base_link.

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-21**:
More generally, the only "discretionary" frames you should have, considering that we are not super users, are the frames below `base_link`. Above `base_link` it should always be `map->odom->base_link`. If you are ever tempted to change this idea, by adding "odom_raw" as a frame or something else like that, you should second guess yourself.

**Comment by [nalistic](https://answers.ros.org/users/55256/nalistic/) on 2020-09-21**:
But right now I have 2 odometry sources and the odometry filtered result from the package, all odometry sources should be in the same Odom frame?

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-21**:
For this case yes. Your robot only has one `odom` frame no matter what happens, the same way it has only one `base_link` or `map` frame.

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-21**:
Also, your `world_frame` should be `odom` if you are only fusing imu and encoder data :)

**Comment by [nalistic](https://answers.ros.org/users/55256/nalistic/) on 2020-09-21**:
Sorry, I did update the code to use odom as world frame, I have tested using the same ID and child frame id but roswtf was complaining about multiple nodes publishing the same tf, should I only publish the Odom frame once? If so, with which positions data? The one returned by the filter?

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-21**:
Its ok, the only node publishing the `odom->base_link` frame should be the `robot_localization` node. That is really the point of the node, to publish the frame. It is not good practice to have multiple nodes publishing the same node for the general case.

**Comment by [nalistic](https://answers.ros.org/users/55256/nalistic/) on 2020-09-24**:
Thanks! that did it, my issue was with tf i was publishing each odometry in a different frame

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-24**:
@nalistic I am happy to hear you found it! To make sure people can debug their own issues and take advantage of your experience you can post and accept an answer to your own question here explaining the original problem, the process you went through, and how exactly you solved it.

**Comment by [nalistic](https://answers.ros.org/users/55256/nalistic/) on 2020-09-24**:
Thanks JackB for the help! my issue was with how my robots TF was set up. The issue had nothing to do with the IMU itself, but when fusing visual and encoders odometry, I had set up each odometry source in different frames, instead of having only once odometry frame with multiple topics.

**Comment by [nalistic](https://answers.ros.org/users/55256/nalistic/) on 2020-09-24**:
I cant see any accept button as in other xxx.answers forumns not even to my or your answer

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-24**:
It is the little checkmark directly below the upvote or downvote button :)

**Comment by [nalistic](https://answers.ros.org/users/55256/nalistic/) on 2020-09-25**:
I have one last question and mayb you could help me, I am using the rf2o package to publish the Laser data to the Odom frame as you explained me before, my issue is that the laser itself is offsetted 15cm and rotated 180 degrees but i have no way to indicate that the LaserOdommetry should be offsetted 15 cm and 180 degrees from the Odom, i am not sure if i am being clear enough

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-26**:
Read the [Transform Configuration](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF) section. Then use a static_transform_publisher from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf). If this doesn't help you, do some more reading and searching and then ask another question.